# Can't manage to link a cpp file - unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linkage

I'm working with Visual Studio 2008. I have a solution with few projects.
On one project (lets call it ProjectX) I have these files:

Header file (ExportProject.h) that look like this:

```
#ifndef __CExportProject_H_INCLUDED__   
#define __CExportProject_H_INCLUDED__

class __declspec(dllimport) CExportProject{

    string func1(... params1 ...);

    void func2(... params2 ...);
}

#endif
```

and a cpp file (ExportProject.cpp):

```
#include "ExportProject.h"

string CExportProject::func1(... params1 ...){
    ...
    return "some string";
}

void CExportProject::func2(){
    string str = func1(... params ...);
}
```

When I'm compiling ProjectX alone, there are no problems.
When I'm trying to compile the solution that contains ProjectX and some other projects I'm getting this error: (this contains the real names of the functions, I just renamed them in order to make the question more clear)

```
PageWorkspace.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall CExportProject::ArgumentsToInApiString(class CInApiHash *,class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class CArgumentsCollection const *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (__imp_?ArgumentsToInApiString@CExportProject@@QAEXPAVCInApiHash@@AAV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PBVCArgumentsCollection@23@2@Z) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall CWorkspacePage::OnExportAsInApi(void)" (?OnExportAsInApi@CWorkspacePage@@IAEXXZ)
```

Clearly, this is a linkage problem. Just to make sure I tried moving the implementation to the header and it worked.

Also, When I'm on the cpp file in the `func2` function and I do right click on the call to `func1` and select "Go To Definition" it takes me to the declaration on the header file instead of the definition in the cpp.

What could be the reason?

**UPDATE**

As I said before, when the implementation is being moved to the header and I remove the `__declspec(dllimport)` it works. With the `__declspec(dllimport)` it doesn't work (Hans Passant explains why in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327911/cant-manage-to-link-a-cpp-file-unresolved-external-symbol#comment30342895_20327911)).

But even without the `__declspec(dllimport)` when the implementation is on the cpp I'm getting the same error (without the __declspec(dllimport) prefix in the error code of course). That indicates the problem, isn't it?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the *complete* error.

Comment: In Visual Studio just including two projects in a solution does not cause them to be linked together.

Comment: All the projects (22 of them) are linked. It's not the first time I'm compiling this solution.

Comment: @ItayGal, ok then the full error message is even more important

Comment: You obfuscated the code too much.  Just arbitrarily throwing a __declspec(dllimport) attribute on a class just isn't going to work.  The class must be __declspec(dllexport) in the project that builds the DLL.  Then another project that uses the DLL must see the exact same class with __declspec(dllimport) and must link the .lib that the DLL project generated.  Missing the last step always generates this linker error.

Comment: @HansPassant Do I really need the __declspec(dllimport) if my problematic class is in the same project? When I remove the __declspec(dllimport) and place the implementation in the header it works. When I move the implementation to the cpp it gives the same error - with or without the __declspec(dllimport)

Comment: Clearly it makes no sense to use dllimport in the project that exports the class.  It must be dllexport.  That always requires using a macro in the .h file.  Check the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant I'm just getting familiar with the code I'm working on, so I'm sorry if my question isn't clear enough. I updated the question. Even without dll import the cpp should be linked inside the project, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the problem and it has nothing to do with the `__declspec(dllimport)`.

I was calling `func2` in some other class defined in the same project.
This call generated the error. When I commented the call the problem was gone.
One of the parameters of `func2` was `CString& str`. Apparently `MFC` was not being used in other Project that includes the lib of the first project where the `func2` was being called, so I couldn't use the `CString`.

Changing it to `std:string` solve the problem.

The one thing that I still don't understand is why I got this error instead of an error that actually indicates the problem. The `func2` was `ArgumentsToInApiString` as you can see in the error code, but still nothing indicated that the Cstring wasn't known.

Comment: I see this issue as well.  Legacy C++ DLL's from VS6.0 to VS2013.  LOTS of projects near circular references. A real mess.  I found this interesting link and fix, but it didn't work for me.  I suspect some module not using MFC. //
// https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/309801/you-may-receive-an-lnk2019-error-message-when-you-build-a-visual-c-2005-or-visual-c-.net-application-that-uses-a-cstring-derived-class-from-a-dll-file
//
template class __declspec(dllimport) CStringT<TCHAR, StrTraitMFC<TCHAR, ChTraitsCRT<TCHAR> > >;
template class __declspec(dllimport) CSimpleStringT<TCHAR>;